# Argument type string is not assignable to parameter type keyof Chainable... in Cypress

Tags: javascript, typescript, cypress

After update 9.0.0 in Cypress I have the following error

Argument type string is not assignable to parameter type keyof Chainable...  Type string is not assignable to type "and" | "as" | "blur" | "check" | "children" | "clear" | "clearCookie" | "clearCookies" | "clearLocalStorage" | "click" | "clock" | ...    Type string is not assignable to type "intercept" which affect all my custom commands

Could someone help me?
[My custom command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tJh6D.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please, include the code in form of a formatted text.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Beginning with version 9.0.0, You are now forced to declare your custom commands.
See the [changelog for 9.0.0](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/changelog#9-0-0) (6th bullet point under breaking changes) and see the specific information about custom commands now being typed based on the declared custom chainable [here](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/pull/17496).

Also, see this [recipe](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-example-recipes/tree/master/examples/fundamentals__add-custom-command) on how to add custom commands and declare them properly.

For your custom command, add this file `cypress/support/index.d.ts` with the following code:

```js
/// <reference types="cypress" />

declare namespace Cypress {
    interface Chainable<Subject = any> {
        /**
         * Custom command to ... add your description here
         * @example cy.clickOnMyJourneyInCandidateCabinet()
         */
        clickOnMyJourneyInCandidateCabinet(): Chainable<null>;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @PeaceAndQuiet, but how do I go about a custom command that has a `prevSubject`? This requires an additional first `subject` argument in the implementation signature, which must be omitted in the interface method signature. And that causes a TypeScript error.

Comment: They seem to have an issue with this new feature.
https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/18879

Comment: Could you post your code from one of your command with a prevSubject? I have a bunch of those and mine are working with 9.0.0.

Comment: Heres's a simple example: https://pastebin.com/Hd0tk2W7 . IntelliJ complains about the arguments, saying that `element` shouldn't be there.

Comment: Using Webstorm here and it doesn't like it either. But my tests are running and passing. Let's hope cypress fixes issue 18879. In the meantime, if you're blocked, you can try the workaround given by the author of the issue.
https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/18879

Answer (score 8):

in support/index.d.ts

```
declare namespace Cypress {
  interface Chainable<Subject = string> {
    preventSubmit(form: string): Chainable<Element>;
  }
}
```

in support/command.js

```
Cypress.Commands.add("preventSubmit", (form) => {
  cy.get(form).then((form$) => {
    form$.on("submit", (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
    });
  });
  cy.log(`prevent default submit to '${form}'`);
});
```

in specs/test.js

```
describe("MyTest", () => {
  ...
  it("Test 1", () => {
    ...
    cy.preventSubmit("form");
    cy.get("form").submit();
  }
}
```