# Argument type string is not assignable to parameter type keyof Chainable ... cypress JS

Tags: javascript, typescript, cypress

So I'm trying to add a custom command in cypress (commands.js file) like so:

```
     Cypress.Commands.add("login", (email, password) => {
      cy.intercept('POST', '**/auth').as('login');
      cy.visit('/auth');
      cy.get('[formcontrolname="email"]').type(email);
      cy.get('[formcontrolname="password"]').type(password);
      cy.get('form').submit();
      cy.wait('@login').then(xhr => {
        expect(xhr.request.body.email).to.equal(email);
        expect(xhr.request.body.password).to.equal(password);
       });
    });
```

but I get this error:

'Argument type string is not assignable to parameter type keyof Chainable ...   Type string is not assignable to type "and" | "as" | "selectFile" | "blur" | "check" | "children" | "clear" | "clearCookie" | "clearCookies" | "clearLocalStorage" | "click" | ...     Type string is not assignable to type "intercept"'

I've found this question [Argument type string is not assignable to parameter type keyof Chainable... in Cypress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69927966/argument-type-string-is-not-assignable-to-parameter-type-keyof-chainable-in-c), but the answers here are only applicable for an index.d.ts file, however I have an index.js file (cypress version 10.3.0 and this is not working for me. Can anyone help me solve this issue?

Comment: It's not clear from the info you've given - is there any typescript in the project? The type argument errors will only occur when the project is seen as typescript.

Comment: Is this error from just defining that part of the custom command? Or are there other statements in the function body. You may have to share the complete stacktrace in your question to get help debugging that.

Comment: The project I'm writting tests for is in typescript, but when I installed cypress, it autocreated files in js (e2e.js, index.js, commands.js) and now I'm unsure of what I'm supposed to do about it.

Comment: Oluwafemi Sule, I've added the entire function body, the logic works, but I still receive the same error

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You shouldn't mix `.js` and `.ts` in a Typescript project.

Make everything `.ts`, then add the `index.d.ts` with a type definition for your custom command.

```js
/// <reference types="cypress" />

declare namespace Cypress {
  interface Chainable<Subject = any> {
    login(): Chainable<any>;
  }
}
```

You may run into more problems, for example check if you have a `tsconfig.json` in the `/cypress` folder.

If in doubt, use [cypress-realworld-app](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-realworld-app) as a reference for Typescript setup.

Comment: Thanks for that. I suspected I would have to change everything to .ts, but thought that there was maybe a workaround.
I changed it now and everything works as it should. Thank you

Comment: Just wanted to add that the `index.d.ts` file should _not_ be in the same folder as your commands. I had it in the `support` folder and I had the error, but the error was resolved when I moved the `index.d.ts` file into the parent (root) Cypress folder.

Comment: It sounds like your `tsconfig.json` was not set correctly.

Comment: https://docs.cypress.io/guides/tooling/typescript-support#Types-for-Custom-Commands

Comment: This should fix it too: `Cypress.Commands.add("login" as any, (email: string, password: string) => {`

Comment: You cannot use `as any` in a `.js` file, it will give you a syntax error.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer gave me two Linting-issues: `'Subject' is defined but never used. eslint(@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars)` as well as `Unexpected any. Specify a different type. (eslint@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any)`. The solution that worked for me without Linting-issues is:

```
// support/index.d.ts
/// <reference types="cypress" />

declare namespace Cypress {
  interface Chainable {
    login(name: string): void;
  }
}
```

Now, when we define commands, TypeScript nicely infers parameter-types properly:

[image]

What still doesn't work though is proper typing for the return type. Following example won't raise any TypeScript error, although the return-type is clearly wrong (should be `void` according to the declaration):

```
Cypress.Commands.add("login", (name) => {
  return name;
})
```

To extend the type-checking to the return-type as well, what you can do is:

```
// declare the function explicitly
const login: Cypress.Chainable["login"] = (name) => {
  // won't work anymore
  // return name;
  return;
};

Cypress.Commands.add("login", login);
```