# Cypress command terminal error: is not assignable to parameter of type keyof Chainable

Tags: angular, testing, cypress, cypress-custom-commands

The Cypress e2e tests run but I do get an error related to Cypress.Commands.add('loginAs'.

My commands are stored in the folders: cypress/support/commands.ts and seem to be used by my e2e tests. So not sure why I get this error.

**I get the following terminal error:**

```
ERROR in cypress/support/commands.ts:1:22 - error TS2345: Argument of type '"loginAs"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'keyof Chainable<any>'.
```

**Tech stack:** Angular v15 and Cypress v12.

**Example of the command in use:**

```
describe('Check if the app is alive and can login', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    cy.loginAs('Super Admin');
  });

  it('See welome page and view courses', () => {
    cy.get(':nth-child(1) > .card-content > .btn', { timeout: 4000 }).scrollIntoView().click();
    cy.url().should('include', '/courses');
  });
});
```

**Example of my cypress command add:**

```
Cypress.Commands.add('loginAs', (role?: string) => {
  const user = Cypress.env('user');
  cy.visit(Cypress.env('local'));
  cy.get('#mat-input-0', { timeout: 30000 }).should('be.visible').type(user.email);
  cy.get('#mat-input-1', { timeout: 30000 }).should('be.visible').type(user.password);
  cy.get('.btn').click({ force: true });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I have actually seen the answer to this question on another stackoverflow question. Here is the link: [Argument type string is not assignable to parameter type keyof Chainable... in Cypress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69927966/argument-type-string-is-not-assignable-to-parameter-type-keyof-chainable-in-c)